# CSS Horizontal Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I have a problem and I do not know how to solve it, I am really a beginner. I am trying to make a navigation bar and reduce a spacing between navigation points but i am so unsuccesful.
here is what I have:[my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz1Y1.png)

and I would like to reduce the spice between it and have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz2Bg.png)

Comment: You need to post your code, not images of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nmttg009/